# how can i run batch file and get output back into the batchfile?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

hi i am using windows 7 and wish to get the output of a cmd command and append it to my batch file that i issued the cmd command with

example

```
@echo off
net user  REM (which will return a list of users on the system)
```

now i want to get one of the users that are returned but without knowing the username and send it back into my batch file as a string such as

```
@echo off
net user
net user REM (and input the returned username here as a string)
```

so i can carry on with the rest of my commented out strings to get account creation logs of my local machine users i need it to be automated in gathering information for my many users

Comment: You really need to use a language a little more sophisticated in the string manipulation area for this.  Batch just isn't up to the task.  Try something WSH would understand (JScript, VBS), or Powershell.

Comment: To capture the output of a command in a batch script, use a `for /f` loop.  Although I suggest `wmic useraccount get name` would be easier to parse than `net user`.  Try this: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in ('wmic useraccount get name^,SID /format:csv ^| find "-"') do @echo Use %%I in a command of some sort`.  If you want to have the script launch itself with the username as an argument, replace that `@echo` stuff with `call "%~f0" %%I`.  That calls self passing the username scraped from wmic as an argument.

Comment: rojo thanks for the answer mate i kind of understand what you mean this is how i have amended my batch but am getting stuck with the do @echo Use %%I in a command of some sort this is my batchfile now as is but it doesnt work yet please explain more clearly what i have to change

Comment: rojo thanks for the answer mate i kind of understand what you mean this is how i have amended my batch but am getting stuck with the do @echo Use %%I in a command of some sort this is my batchfile now as is but it doesnt work yet please explain more clearly what i have to change